# Java calls Powershell using proc.waitFor(), cannot get correct return code

Tags: java, powershell, exit-code

I'm having a problem with Java calling a powershell script. 
This is the sample testing Java program that I'm using:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.text.*;

public class testJava
{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String cmd = "";
        Process proc;
        int exitVal;

        try {
            sb = new StringBuffer();
            sb.append("powershell C:\\test\\return_sth.ps1");
            cmd = sb.toString();
            proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
            proc.getOutputStream().close(); 
            exitVal = proc.waitFor();

            System.out.println("exitVal = " + exitVal);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The powershell script "return_sth.ps1" is:

```
exit 123
```

I find that I cannot get "123" in the Java's variable "exitVal". 
Instead, I get exitVal = "1". 
Actually, all exit codes OTHER THAN 0 (including negative codes like -1) from the powershell script becomes "1" in exitVal.

I would like to know how to properly capture the exit code in Java from the powershell script. After testing, I have found an alternative way that CAN achieve the goal, but I think it looks a bit clumsy and not clever:

Replace the Java's sb.append line with

```
sb.append("powershell.exe -Command \"C:\\test\\return_sth.ps1;exit $lastexitcode\"");
```

Is my new way a way to go? Or is there a nicer, more tidy calling method to get the exit code from powershell?
Please advise, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Exit code are be absorbed due to the chain of the calls from `java -> powershell -> script` forked executions if you use the `-command` argument, however for `-File` argument, the exit-code / errorlevel is passed directly over to the parent process.

With regards, I recommend to use `-file` to passthru the exitcode properly in your case:

```
powershell -file C:\test\return_sth.ps1
```

On the other hand, if you wish to use the `-command` parameter your example is perfectly fine too.